# Converting to Date Format in Arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, excel

i have ab Excel table which it's fields are (year,month,day,hour,AM/Pm), how to convert those Fields into a Date format table in Arcgis and then creating a time frame Visualization.

Answer (score 1):

If the cells are date format you can just use the [ExcelToTable](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000055000000) tool.  Which is new at  10.2.  The tool converts xls, xlsx to a gdb table and handles dates correctly.

On 10.1, you can download and use an earlier version of the functionality [here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f3d91b8f852042e289e09a7ec8342431).

If the cells are a string, you can use python's [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to convert the string to a datetime object .  What i'd do is import your excel to gdb, add a new 'actual_date' field, and use the CalculateField tool to convert the text field to a datefield.

Comment: and how to convert the 4 fields into date format field???

Comment: Use the [convert date format](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000v2000000) tool

Comment: The Year , Month , Day Fields are each separated and the Month Field format is Like this "FEB,APR....." so it didn't work

Comment: oh, use calc field and set the expression as toDate(!Year!, !Month!, !Day!), and set the codeblock to "def toDate(y,m,d):  datetime.strptime(...)"